# Cannot pin a certain drive to Quick Access in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11, windows-10-quick-access

I have pinned several drives and folders to `Quick Access` in Windows 11. No problems. But I have an F-drive that is 7 Tb that will not pin to quick access. The pin option is available, as you can see:

[image]

...but it does nothing. I even tried rebooting, thinking maybe the windows explorer cache was stuck or something. No dice.

How is it done? If there's no way, can I hack the registry to get it to show up? Is there a limit to how many items I can pin to quick access? I don't think I have an excessive amount, as you can see:

[image]

Comment: Try removing one of the items then adding the item that does not want to seem to be added. There is a hard limit to the number of items that can be pinned.

Comment: That would be an awfully small limit.

Comment: This isn't the case, I was successful in pinning 25+ folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is more of a yeet-it-all, however this might work.

There is a file in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`, with name `f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms`. This file stores the information about the folders you've pinned. What I think is, this file somehow got corrupted on your computer, yk, since Windows 11 is still under development. When you delete this file, it is automatically remade within second — And you'll get desktop, documents, downloads, and pictures pinned by default. You can pin `F:\` immediately after.

Comment: Saaransh, this is fantastic! Worked perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: BTW, after deleting that funky file, the Quick Access in file explorer was completely empty - it didn't have those defaults you mentioned. Totally fine by me!

Comment: Hmm. Maybe things changed a bit for Windows 11!

Comment: Still a relevant solution.  I needed this fix after I changed the default location of the Documents folder to a folder on my Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Open a PowerShell session and enter the following commands:

```powershell
$o = new-object -com shell.application
$o.Namespace('F:\').Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome")
```

If this fails to work, then is there something special about the F: drive?

Comment: Didn't work, but I'm concerned about `pintohome` because I wanted to pin in to windows explorer `Quick Access` and not to home. The F: drive is an internal drive in my PC. It's not external/portable/virtual/mapped, nothing unusual.

Comment: `pintohome` is documented as pertaining to Quick Access, but this is easy to test. Is `F:` perhaps shared over the network, has a different owner than yourself, or some other particularity?

Comment: It was shared, but I unshared it. It was owned by `System` but I changed it to `Everyone` (my own logged-in user account didn't display in the list!?). Tried again to add it to Quick Access, tried again the powershell script. Still nothing works. `F:` still won't appear in windows explorer quick access.

Comment: The `Everyone` pseudo-account is not a good choice - select instead your own user account.

Comment: As stated, my own user account doesn't show up. It's not in the list of accounts in the folder properties -> Advanced -> Ownership. I don't understand why.

Comment: Is your account local or Microsoft?

Comment: I believe it's Microsoft, not local. This is a work PC.

Comment: Try making the owner a local account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134127/discussion-between-herrimancoder-and-harrymc).

Answer (score 0):

Incase you're struggling with this issue on Windows 11, I found the following link. Running it through cmd worked instantly.

[Clear and Reset Quick Access Folders in Command Prompt](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/clear-and-reset-quick-access-folders-in-windows-11.4693/)

Copy and then paste this into Command Prompt:

del /f /s /q /a "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\f01b4d95cf55d32a.automaticDestinations-ms"

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, and thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately "This is how you reset Quick Access folders" isn't quite an answer to question "How do I pin drive X to Quick Access". As you're new here, it's a good idea to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and check at least the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/tour) to learn how these sites work.